# How to listen specific key that's pressed in a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, events, keyboard, backspace

I need to detect backspace key in a TextField.

I found `RawKeyboardListener` widget but it only works for physical keyboards. When I press backspace using the phone keyboard, is does not trigger.
I need something like RawKeyboardListener, but that's able to detect phone keyboard events

Comment: tried `FocusNode.onKey*` ?

Comment: @pskink it only detects physical keyboard events, the same as RawKeyboardListener